# Camunda: View Prozess Values

Tags: camunda

In the Moment i play with Camunda 7.3
http://docs.camunda.org/7.3/guides/getting-started-guides/java-ee/
this example shows how the data flows through the prozess tasks and how the java parts gets information from the prozess (    orderEntity.setCustomer((String) variables.get("customer"));)

so long all clear and cool but my question is: 
could i see while modelling or dev time which values ar avaible in the prozess? in the excample a developer must know that the value has the name customer and after 1month of dev time we have a customer, a user and a custoomer value in the prozess :-)

how could i see or organize the values which are used in the prozess?
i could not be the only one how has this wish.

only to my understandig of the usecase of the camunda engine: it should organize the prozess values and the work flow.

Thanks!

many thanks!

Lars (sw arc from germany)

Comment: Hello nobody an idea? Or is my problem not a problem and i use camunda false? So please tell me: how could a developer see on one place how an prozess work? he hat to look at every single task (and the code) and where are two lines of truth (the prozess and the code). I didnt see how the prozess way was clearer than the hard coded way. I want to belive /know it: please give me a hint/best practise how to do this. The example (DAPattern) was a good way but not exact what i am searching for. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Camunda you do not have to declare your variables somewhere.

If want to do that, you can do so using [I/O mappings](http://docs.camunda.org/7.3/guides/user-guide/#process-engine-process-variables-inputoutput-variable-mapping)

It is also best practice to group variable access in a single java class (Data Accessor Pattern). See this [example](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-consulting/blob/master/snippets/data-in-processes/src/test/java/org/camunda/consulting/patterns/data/ExampleProcessDataAccessor.java). This way you can easily see at a single glance which variables exist, and which Java classes read/write them using you IDE.

Comment: I want to see on one view where in the prozess which values are used and changed. IOMapping => cool but not that i want to do. The Data Accessor Pattern => only a minimal helper for the using of Values. A nearly similar solution was my first  throw). Is in the prozess view no availability to see how the data flows? Or only in the Enterprice System? I am an SW Arc who evaluates the Camunda BPMN System. In the Moment it shows that i must manage the prozesses and the java code (not a single point of thruth) an must click to a lot of fields to see where the data is changed. thanks lars

Answer (score 0):

You can actually check the running processes inside **cockpit** to find out the variables unless you want to do it from service side.

```
    runtimeService.getVariables(processInstanceId);
```